# javascript setting attribute of prototype to attribute of object

Tags: javascript, reference, attributes, three.js, prototype

To begin with, I don't fully understand the prototypal structure of Javascript so this may not be possible.

If I have ...

```
var vector = function( x, y ) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}

var obj = function() {
    this.position = new vector( 0, 0, 0 );
}

var cube = new obj();
```

... how can I add a property `x` to `obj` such that calling `cube.x` is equivalent to `cube.position.x`. I think it should be possible to make properties of each reference the same value, but I'm just not sure of the syntax. Something like `obj.prototype.x = obj.position.x` doesn't work because `obj.position` is undefined.

I would like the following behaviour to be possible

```
alert(cube.position.x); // 0
alert(cube.x); // 0

cube.position.x = 2;
alert(cube.position.x); // 2
alert(cube.x); // 2

cube.x = 4;
alert(cube.position.x); // 4
alert(cube.x); // 4
```

Is this possible?

I should probably mention that I'm working with Three.js so rewriting the objects isn't an option, just adding to them and their prototypes.

Comment: You can only do this in browsers that support [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FWorking_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `cube.x` to return whatever `cube.position.x` contains, you'd need to define accessors and mutators for `obj.prototype.x`. Accessors and mutators are a relatively newer feature in JavaScript, and are not supported in most versions of IE.

```
var vector = function( x, y ) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}

var obj = function() {
    this.position = new vector( 0, 0, 0 );
}
obj.prototype = {
    ...your prorotype methods here...
};
Object.defineProperty(obj.prototype, 'x', {
    get: function () {
        return this.position.x;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        this.position.x = val;
    }
});

//alternatively:
obj.prototype = {
    get x() {
        return this.position.x;
    },
    set x(val) {
        this.position.x = val;
    }
};

var cube = new obj();
cube.x; //0
cube.x = 10;
cube.position.x; //10
```

Comment: @alex23, the point was to show a placeholder of where the prototype would be declared.

Comment: You are awesome! Haven't heard of accessors and mutators before. I guess that's why I couldn't find an answer online.  What are the differences between `Object.defineProperty(obj.prototype, 'x', {});` and `obj.prototype = {};`. Are they both accepted standards? Is one faster?

Comment: using `get x()` and `set x()` in a literal is for convenience. `Object.defineProperty` is meant for being able to dynamically build accessors and mutators. Just remember that whatever you write using these accessors and mutators won't be backwards compatible.

Comment: @alex23, the point of overriding the prototype with an object literal is to avoid constantly calling `Class.prototype.foo = ...; Class.prototype.bar = ...; Class.prototype.baz = ...;`. It's such a common convention that I threw it in as a placeholder. You could certainly leave it off if you're not adding methods to the prototype, however you'll need to make sure the `Object.defineProperty` call happens after you change the prototype if you *are* overriding the prototype.